# Play / pause mp3 files in Windows Phone MVVM application

Tags: mvvm-light, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I am trying to play small mp3 file in my Windows Phone 7.5 MVVM application (MVVM Light is used).

I am trying:

**1st.** To use `SoundEffect`:

```
SoundEffectInstance instance;
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
instance = effect.CreateInstance();
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
instance.Play();
```

Problem: only .wav files allowed.

**2nd.** To use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song song = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song.FromUri("name", new Uri("someUri"));
```

Problem: file is stored in the `IsolatedStrorage` and we need to know the full path to the file.

Suggested hint:

```
string path = stream.GetType().GetField("m_FullPath", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(stream).ToString();
```

is not working.

**3d.** To use standard `MediaElement`.

Problem: I need an access to the `MediaElement` control in the `ViewModel` which is not good from the MVVM view.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this in the MVVM style is to use the MVVM Light Messenger class to send play/pause messages from the viewmodel, which the view would subscribe to and receive.

Say you have a pair of Buttons on your view for Play and Pause.  You would drop an [EventToCommand behavior](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/05/windows-phone-from-scratch-mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-part-2/) on each of them in Expression Blend, and then you would bind them to a pair of RelayCommand properties in your viewmodel, one RelayCommand for Play, one for Pause.  For example, in your viewmodel, you would have:

```
public RelayCommand PlayCommand { get; private set; }
public RelayCommand PauseCommand { get; private set; }
```

The Play command would have the Messenger send a Play message, and the Pause command would send a Pause message.  Each message would be its own simple class:

```
public class PlayMessage { }
public class PauseMessage { }
```

Then, in the constructor of your viewmodel, you would create new RelayCommands for the two RelayCommand properties you created earlier that would have actions that have the Messenger send the messages:

```
MyViewModel()
{
    PlayCommand = new RelayCommand( () => SendPlayMessage() );
    PauseCommand = new RelayCommand( () => SendPauseMessage() );
}

private void SendPlayMessage()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<PlayMessage>( new PlayMessage() );
}

private void SendPauseMessage()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send<PauseMessage>( new PauseMessage() );
}
```

Your view would then [have the Messenger subscribe](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/06/windows-phone-from-scratch%E2%80%93mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-3/) to both of these message types, and would have actions that would call the Play and Pause methods on the MediaElement:

```
MyView()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<PlayMessage>
    (
        this,
        ( action ) => ReceivePlayMessage( action )
    );
    Messenger.Default.Register<PauseMessage>
    (
        this,
        ( action ) => ReceivePauseMessage( action );
    );
}

private void ReceivePlayMessage(PlayMessage msg)
{
    myMediaElement.Play();
}

private void ReceivePauseMessage(PauseMessage msg)
{
    myMediaElement.Pause();
}
```

Where myMediaElement is the name you give to the MediaElement in your view's xaml.